# Finding siblings through a joins table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have models User, Group, and Membership with the following structure:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end

class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Basically, Membership is the joins table for User and Group.

Given a User `user`, how can I find its sibling users who all belong to at least one of the same group? That is, something like

```
user.groups.users # assuming such a line were possible
```

I'd like to do it in a single query and solely in Active Record, but I'm OK with two queries if that's faster or much more readable. (The DB language is PSQL if that helps as well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ways to combine JOINs and sub-selects to get exactly one DB query, try this one:

```
User
  .joins(:memberships)
  .where.not(id: user.id)
  .where(
    memberships: {
      group_id: user.memberships.select(:group_id)})
```

P.S. Don't forget about indexes on all *_id columns to get fast queries.
P.P.S. One more way: 2 sub-selects, 1 DB query. Test which one suits your requirements better:

```
user_groups_rel = user
  .memberships
  .select(:group_id)
groups_users_rel = Membership
  .select(:user_id)
  .where(group_id: user_groups_rel)
User
  .where.not(id: user.id)
  .where(id: groups_users_rel)
```

Comment: Thank you! I know I'm not supposed to just leave thank you comments, but this works great, and subselecting the IDs is clever. (And yes, I have the indices :) )

Comment: Oh, one comment though: realized this could use a `distinct` at the end to prevent duplicates.

Comment: Yes, result is Relation, so you can chain it as you wish. Also, you can try `include` instead of `joins` - need no `distinct`, but additional memory will be spent of AR objects instantiating. Just added one more variant.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following by using `includes`:

```
groups = User.groups.includes(:users)
groups.each do |group|
  puts "user = #{group.user}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't return an AR relation, and even if a simple array were usable, this answer would have to be improved by doing `user.groups.includes(:users).map(&:users).flatten.uniq`